# Have a for loop return a dataframe when it produces a string

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, yfinance

I have a list of tickers I need to retrieve the name for. I am trying to write a loop that returns a dataframe containing the `Short_Name` and the `tic` name.

Code below:

```
a = []
b = ['FFIV', 'FIS', 'FISV', 'FITB', 'FLS', 'FMC']

for i in b: #add 5 rows of data
    stock = yf.Ticker(i)
    a['Short_Name'] = stock.info['shortName']
    a['tic'] = i
```

Unfortunately when I run this code I get the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
a = []
b = ['FFIV', 'FIS', 'FISV', 'FITB', 'FLS', 'FMC']

for i in b: #add 5 rows of data
    stock = yf.Ticker(i)
    a.append([stock.info['shortName'], i])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=a, columns=['Short_Name', 'tic'])
```